How to add top level redirect on AWS Route 53?
I need to change domain name on aws Route 53, however I have multiple sub-domains as well. For example foo.com is my top level domain, however I also have app.foo.com and admin.foo.com.
I would like to set a single redirect for foo.com, for example to bar.com, and automatically change all sub-domains to redirect traffic to [subdomain].bar.com. So admin.foo.com would redirect to admin.bar.com. Is it possible to setup a single top level redirect that also affects all sub-domains?

Redirecting a domain like foo.com and all its subdomains (app.foo.com, admin.foo.com, etc.) to a new domain (bar.com) while preserving the subdomain structure can’t be done directly in Route 53 as far as I know.
But you can use CloudFront and Lambda@edge to use it as a middleware and do this redirection for you.
You just need to change domain names as CNAME pointing to the cloudfront and create the Lambda as a flexible and scalable way to handle dynamic redirection for all subdomains.

There would be a solution involving a new CloudFront and a new Route53 hosted zone. With the following approach, you will keep all your existing Route53 records in your current hosted zone intact so you’ll be able to switch back easily if anything goes wrong.
Steps:

Create a Cloudfront distribution

Create a certificate with both apex foo.com and wildcard subdomain *.foo.com and attach it to your new Cloudfront

Create a new Cloudfront Function by adapting this AWS tutorial with following (not tested):
async function handler(event) {
    const request = event.request;
    const host = request.headers.host.value;
    const path = request.uri;
    const newHost = host.replace("foo.com", "bar.com"); // Will replace just the host and will keep subdomain
    var newurl = `https://${newHost} + path`;
    var response = {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: { "location": { "value": newurl } }
    }
    return response;
}


Attach the new Cloudfront Function to the Cloudfront on the viewer request on the default behavior

Create a new hosted zone in Route53

Add following entries to your Route53:

foo.com A alias record pointing to the Cloudfront URL
*.foo.com A alias record pointing to the Cloudfront URL



Note that both entries are required as APEX domain and subdomains are processed differently.

Copy the NS entries of your new Route53 hosted zone
Go to your registrar and update the NS entries of your foo.com domain with the NS entries from your new Route53 hosted zone

In your case, you will have only limited options, because the main issue is that wildcards DNS record don’t take precedence (For example, if you create records for *.example.com and acme.example.com, Route 53 always responds to DNS queries for acme.example.com with the values in the acme.example.com record.)…
